# Can't access HTML child tags with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to access article metadata from CNN's website. Their "top news" section is beneath a tag that starts like this:

```
<section class="zn zn-homepage1-zone-1....
```

Beneath that section, each article is inside of tag that looks like this:

```
<article class="cd cd--card cd--article....
```

On similar websites, I am able to access the "top news" stories with the following approach:

```
cnnUrl = "https://www.cnn.com"
cnnSoup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(cnnUrl, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")

homepageZone1 = '[class*="zn zn-homepage1-zone-1"]'

for item in cnnSoup.select(homepageZone1):
```

...and the for loop will give me access to the child tags, where I can gather the data I need. Once I have `item`, I can typically do something like this for CNN's lead story headline text (this format varies from time to time):

```
headline = item.find('h2').get_text()
```

Where `headline` would be (as of right now):

> A Petri Dish For the Country

However, in this case I am getting a `None` type for the `homepageZone1` tag. I tried backing out to the parent div of `homepageZone1`:

```
cnnEverything = '[class*="pg-no-rail pg-wrapper"]'

for item in cnnSoup.select(cnnEverything):
```

`Item` here gives me the following child tags, but none of these tags actually have any children I can access:

```
<div class="pg-no-rail pg-wrapper"><div class="pg__background__image_wrapper"></div><div class="l-container"></div><section class="zn--idx-0 zn-empty"> </section><section class="zn--idx-1 zn-empty"> </section><section class="zn--idx-2 zn-empty"> </section><section class="zn--idx-3 zn-empty"> </section><section class="zn--idx-4 zn-empty"> </section><section class="zn--idx-5 zn-empty"> </section><section class="zn--idx-6 zn-empty"> </section><section class="zn--idx-7 zn-empty"> </section><section class="zn--idx-8 zn-empty"> </section><section class="zn--idx-9 zn-empty"> </section><section class="zn--idx-10 zn-empty"> </section><div class="ad ad--epic ad--all t-dark"><div class="ad-ad_bnr_btf_02 ad-refresh-adbody" data-ad-id="ad_bnr_btf_02" id="ad_bnr_btf_02"></div></div></div>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the expected output, can you pls include that in your post.

Comment: Are you sure there are <select> elements with the specified classes in the returned HTML? I just tried it and I get nothing with the zn* classes. However, if I try (for example) www.cnn.com/world I do see those classes

Comment: @AndyKnight interestingly enough, it does not. However, if I inspect a headline using my browser's web inspector, I see that class. Why is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

I think the HTML you need is requested in a separate request and then Javascript is used to add it into the main HTML (which is why you don't see it).

The following shows how to request the international version from the HTML inside the returned JSON:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# International version
r = requests.get("https://edition.cnn.com/data/ocs/section/index.html:intl_homepage1-zone-1/views/zones/common/zone-manager.izl")
json_data = r.json()
html = json_data['html'].replace(r'\"', '"')
cnnSoup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for heading in cnnSoup.find_all(['h2', 'h3']):
    print(heading.text)
```

Giving you the following headlines:

```
Kandahar falls to Taliban
Militants take control of Afghanistan's second-largest city during an unrelenting sweep of the country, weeks before US troops are due to complete withdrawal
LIVE: UK defense chief worried about potential return of al Qaeda
Video allegedly shows Taliban celebrating after Kandahar gain
Afghanistan's quick unraveling threatens to stain Biden's legacy
...
```

The URL was found by looking at the requests made by the browser whilst the page loaded.